# How can I have multiple passphrases for unlocking one encrypted partition?

Tags: partitioning, 15.10, encryption

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 and encrypted my partition with the default partitioning tool that is being displayed during installation. Now I want to be able to give my Laptop to somebody else without having to decrypt my drive and without giving him my passphrase. I already have a second user for him, but he doesn't even get to the point where you can login yourself because he can't encrypt the drive. So is it possible to have 2 keys for encryption?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, LUKS supports multiple keyslots (8 for LUKS v1, [32 for LUKS v2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/553700/23363)) which all can unlock the master key.

See the manpage of `cryptsetup` on how to manage LUKS keyslots. E.g. if your LUKS partition is /dev/sda2, then:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sda2
```

While you're at it, also consider providing an `--iter-time N` (were `N` is the time in miliseconds) option to lower the risk of bruteforcing a keyslot. E.g. for a 2 seconds hashing time:

```
sudo cryptsetup --iter-time 2000 luksAddKey /dev/sda2
```

to list your current key slots:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sda2
```

Adding a new key slot first is also how I would recommende to *change* a current passphrase. First add a new one with the instruction above, reboot, verify the new passphrase works (you never know about keyboard layout mismatches etc.), then delete the old keyslot.

```
sudo cryptsetup luksRemoveKey /dev/sda2
```

You'll then be asked to provide the passphrase to be removed.

In case you want to remove a key slot without providing the current passphrase, you can use `luksKillSlot`, but do that with great care and be sure to provide the right slot ID.